# Who was the first philosopher to use the term "free will"?

Tags: history

When in Leviticus 22:18 "freewill" offerings are mentioned, the concept is related to an offering not specified by Old Testament law but, rather, emanating from a grateful heart.

In this context "freewill" started as a religious term. I speculate that having started it was used by philosophers to mean whatever meaning they gave it.

Maybe that is where it started life but whether it did or not, which philosopher first used it as a philosophic concept?

Comment: See Michael Frede, [A Free Will : Origins of the Notion in Ancient Thought (California UP, 2011)](https://books.google.it/books?id=w7owDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover): "Frede begins with Aristotle (who, he argues, had no notion of a free will) and ends with Augustine. Frede shows that Augustine, far from originating the idea (as is often claimed), derived most of his thinking about it from the Stoicism developed by Epictetus."

Comment: See also SEP's entry on [Free Will](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/freewill/#MajoHistCont).

Comment: Obviously, the modern concept is due to Augustine; see [De libero arbitrio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_libero_arbitrio_(Augustine_book)).

Comment: "Freewill" did not start with the Old Testament. This [translation dates back](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/freewill) to the King James Bible of 1611, philosophers were using *liberum arbitrium* for a long time by then. Nor is the concept (unlike the phrase) due to Augustine, who applied it to theology. It already emerged in the libertarian/compatibilist debates between ancient Stoics and Epicureans, Greeks used the expression *τὸ ἐφ’ ἡμίν*, see [Free will in antiquity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_will_in_antiquity).